# GPU usage with conda env

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, gpu, conda

I am using Anaconda. I have created two new env for TensorFlow and PyTorch. with TensorFlow, I can use GPU but for the PyTorch env when I try to access env I am not able to use GPU I tried reinstalling torch libraries but nothing works how can I access GPU with torch env can anyone suggest to me there are no error messages also when I am installing the dependencies. I am expecting some solution with which I can use the torch env for gpu.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example